# Guidelines or rules of thumb for mobile web design (HTML5, Android, iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, html, mobile-website

There are multiple posts on SO describing the various screen resolutions available on Android.

My question is whether there are any rules of thumbs, or general advice, for designing on Android screens.  For instance, on the desktop web, one rule of thumb i have heard is to design for a width of ~ 970 pixels.

This question could address both native apps and web apps on Android.

We're also curious to hear any similar suggestions for the iPhone (though I believe there is a post somewhere that discusses this).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing worth mentioning is to *not* used a fixed layout. Try as long as possible to use strictly relative layouts for your application (since there are such a vast amount of different screen sizes with various resolutions etc.). A good layout using relative measures can get you a long way.

The [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) section on the Android Developer pages will provide you with some good information.

Answer (score 0):

Google just updated the developer documentation with [coverage of mobile web design](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html) for Android.